# ¿Problema con cubo olap?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

estoy realizando un cubo olap en visual studio 2017, pero al procesar el cubo me sale este error:

> No se puede implementar el proyecto en el servidor 'localhost' debido a los siguientes problemas de conexión:
>   'No se puede establecer una conexión. Asegúrese de que el servidor se esté ejecutando.'.
>   Para comprobar o actualizar el nombre del servidor de destino, haga clic con el botón derecho del mouse (ratón) en el proyecto en el Explorador de soluciones, seleccione Propiedades del proyecto, haga clic en la pestaña Implementación y especifique el nombre del servidor.

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

---

hice todo lo que me sugirieron, pero me sigue saliendo error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Como el error indica, debes de **comprobar o actualizar el nombre del servidor de destino**

Para ello debes de hacer click derecho sobre tu proyecto e ir a las propiedades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez ahí, accede a la sección de  implementación, y verifica que el nombre de la base de datos y del servidor sea igual a las instancias de SQL Server:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Puntos a considerar:** La instancia del servidor SQL a donde te conectas tiene que tener instalada la característica de SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS), para ello la edicion de SQL Server debe de ser Standar o Enterprise.

Si ya cuentas con lo anterior,  tambien verifica que los siguientes servicios se encuentren ejecutando:

(Yo aqui tengo dos instancias de SQL Server: SQLEXPRESS Y MSSQLSERVER en la misma PC)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]